# UPDATE and REPLACE query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update and replace the string value of my data:

```
UPDATE STGOrderDetail
SET [Order ID] = REPLACE([Order ID],'USA%','US-%')
WHERE [Ship Mode] LIKE 'Standard Class'
AND [Order ID] LIKE 'USA%'
```

There was no error, but then, when I check the data, nothing was changed. Tried a different column though:

```
UPDATE STGOrderDetail
SET [Ship Mode] = REPLACE([Ship Mode],'Std Class','Standard Class')
WHERE [Ship Mode] LIKE 'Std Class'
AND [Order ID] LIKE 'USA%'
```

This query works perfectly and after, i was able to see the changes but not the other way around.

Comment: By the way, after running the query, it shows that there were rows affected but could not see the changes.

Comment: Instead of updating your question with a comment, update the body of the question. Use the `edit` button for it.

Comment: @jpenna, a tiny hint: You can use `[edit]` in your comment's text. This will be replaced by a link implicitly: [edit]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to **find** records with `USA` at the beginning, you will use `LIKE 'USA%'`, If this fragment was within the text, you would need `LIKE '%USA%'`.

But the `REPLACE()` functions does not use a pattern. It will find the string you pass into *exactly*, and replace it with the second string. If your values do not include the string **"USA%"** (including the `%`!) nothing will be replaced...

Try this (careful with real data)

```
UPDATE STGOrderDetail
SET [Order ID] = REPLACE([Order ID],'USA','US-')
WHERE [Ship Mode] LIKE 'Standard Class'
AND [Order ID] LIKE 'USA%'
```

Any row which **begins** with *USA* will be handled.
Careful: **Any occurance of *USA* (anywhere in the string)** will be replaced by *US-*

Comment: Thank you brother. Was able to use the query successfully. My fault as well for I am placing the '%' on the REPLACE() Statement. Thanks again